# iText support for HIndi and Arabic

Tags: itext, glyph, hindi

Our project needs dynamic PDF generation in 6 languages which consists of Hindi and Arabic. iText works brilliantly for other languages except these two. Can someone let me know if current version of iText(5.5.5) have ligature implementation for Hindi and Arabic?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I'm working on the Indic languages but you already have good support with Arabic, just don't forget to set the writing direction.

Comment: @PauloSoares: Thanks for your quick reply. Rendering Arabic text is not a problem but similar to Hindi, we are facing problem of Glyphs (Joint characters not rendered properly) in Arabic language. How soon we can get Hindi support in iText?

Comment: It's a couple of months away. Regarding Arabic can you post some examples where the rendering is incorrect?

Comment: @PauloSoares - did you get success with indian language..???

Comment: eagerly waiting for hindi support.

Answer (score 0):

about Arabic language:
I understand you face one of two problems:

- the Arabic words don't appear.
- the Arabic words appears like :

[image]

the solution is:

- first: update your itext 5.5.8 to itext 7 implementation:

> https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core/7.2.2/pom
>
> - then edit your code:

```
String font = "your Arabic font";
PdfFontFactory.register(font);
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font, true);
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
LanguageProcessor languageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument tempPdfDoc = new 
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile.getPath()), TempWriter);
com.itextpdf.layout.Document TempDoc = new 
com.itextpdf.layout.Document(tempPdfDoc);
com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph paragraph0 = new 
com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph(languageProcessor.process("الاستماره الالكترونية"))
            .setFont(f).setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
            .setFontSize(15);
```

> //and look how i useded setBaseDirection & and don't use TextAlignment ,it will work without it